# Problem with querying related data in ef core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.0

I have a problem build query which give me in result all courses of concrete userid. Below piece of model.
[image]

I want to retrieve all enrolment courses of concrete user by id. I made sth like that

```
return await _card_App_DbContext.User.Where(a => a.Id == id)
                    .Include(user => user.CourseEnrolment)
                    .ThenInclude(courseEnrolment => courseEnrolment.Course).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Which gave me enrolment course of user but only this which this user create
Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Already found solution. My mapping skipped intersection it was mapping properly